# Ways to connect touchscreen to rpi zero

Tags: connection

I understand a touchscreen can be connected to the rpi zero either via the dsi interface and a short ribbon cable, or through HDMI and USB. I want to place the rpi at a different location than the display (due to that the rpi will be controlling things and needs a number of cable connections).
Is it better to prolong the DSI ribbon cable (up to 2 meters?) or better to use HDMI/USB interface to connect between them?

Answer (score 1):

It may actually be easier to put the Pi next to the display and prolong the connections to the "things" the Pi is controlling. I bet those things need much less data than a video signal, so the probability their connections will work fine over a distance is much higher.

Comment: I will go for the HDMI plus USB for the touch feedback as there are quite a few relay and analog signals I don't want to route to the display.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that long dsi cables don't always work well. HDMI works, but you need a usb/gpio touch interface. But there are a million only GPIO displays on ebay, and long wires can work. (Hopefully these links dont go dead: check out [this screen](https://thepihut.com/products/hdmi-5-800x480-touch-screen-and-case-gpio), [these wires](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077ZP3NNJ), and [these headers](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3663).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advise.  I will go for the  HDMI plus USB for touch feedback . There are quite a few relays and analog signals to the pi and I don't want to route them to the display.

Regarding USB, I want to use the zero in order to get low standby power consumption.  However I need more than one USB, but it should be no problem to connect an externally powered USB hub to the zero I expect.